# Difference between <> and NOT in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small table which looks like this:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+
| firstName | middleName | lastName |
+-----------+------------+----------+
| Harish    | NULL       | Salve    |
| John      | Ford       | Kennedy  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
```

When I runs the query:
`select firstName, lastName from people where middleName <> NULL;` 
I get an empty set.

But when I runs:
`select firstName, lastName from people where middleName is not null;`
I gets the desired result:

```
+-----------+----------+
| firstName | lastName |
+-----------+----------+
| John      | Kennedy  |
+-----------+----------+
```

I thought both `<>` and `NOT` are same. Is there something wrong in my first query? If not, then what is the actual difference between the two.

ps: I am using MySQL.

Comment: `NULL` is a special value in SQL. You can only test it with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Barmar or `<=>`

Comment: Indeed, careful how your database is setup, if it defaults to put NULL into blank slots, when you go to pull data it doesn't find "" blank slot, but rather NULL, and most languages testing a string for NOTHING like "" is not the same code to check ISNULL sort of thing, so just be very aware.  Also if you delete records with statements, make sure to renull them and not just blank out the data, unless that is what you want.